# Young-friendly things

Tags: expressions

What do the Americans call something which is young friendly and something that is enjoyable for youths:

> - That type of *games* are **young-friendly**.
> - That type of *games* **hip with the kids**.

----- OR ------

> - These sport *shoes* are **young-friendly**.
> - These sport *shoes* **hip with the kids**.

If none of these choices work, please tell me the correct word/expression for that.

Comment: Note: "hip" is no a verb, you still need the "are".

Comment: "Youth-friendly" could sound better, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally say "These sport shoes are ***kid*-friendly**."

A Google search for "kid-friendly" gives over 88 million hits, while "young-friendly" has only 64 million, with most on the first page actually being "young, friendly". Adding quotes for an exact match gives 50m:25k.

As for "That type of games hip with the kids":

First of all, if you're going to use that phrase at all, it sounds like it should be "That type of *game are* hip with the kids." But "hip with the kids" isn't too common (even fewer hits than "young-friendly"!) May i suggest "**popular with the kids**"?

Comment: Thank you Scimonster. :)
Just what do you think of the word 'kids'?! I guess whereas 'kid' refers to children bellow a specific age, this expression "popular with the kids" cannot be used e.g. for a 28 years old young person. Then for such age what would be your suggestion? ;)

Comment: I think it would be relative to the age of the speaker. A middle-aged adult could probably refer to anyone under 18-20. If it's a teenager saying it, younger than 10. A real old geezer (older than 80) could even refer to someone 25 years old as a "kid".

Comment: But supposing I am 30 years old and I'm speaking to my friend about a sport coat. Can I tell him that "this coat really looks popular with the kids"? Does this sentence make a sense to you? Is it idiomatic?